# create phonegap app using commande line

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

i try to create a phonegap application using cmd line `create C:\testapp com.demo.testapp testapp` i got this message `something wrong in the loop` 
when i execute this commande i call the create.bat file which contain :

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME GOTO MISSING
FOR %%X in (java.exe javac.exe ant.bat android.bat) do (
    SET FOUND=%%~$PATH:X
    IF NOT DEFINED FOUND GOTO MISSING2
)
cscript "%~dp0\create.js" %*
GOTO END
:MISSING
ECHO Missing one of the following:
ECHO JDK: http://java.oracle.com
ECHO Android SDK: http://developer.android.com
ECHO Apache ant: http://ant.apache.org
:MISSING2
ECHO something wrong in the loop
EXIT /B 1
```

**so how can i fix the problem of java.exe , javac.exe, ant.bat and android.bat or how can i modify create.bat code ?!**

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that  ant.bat does not exist ! i download the apache-ant-x.x.x-bin.zip and i extracted the file and i added the `ant bin` to my `path` variable and that's work correctly 
and i used this `phonegap` zip for `android` [cordova-android.zip](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) which contain the correct `create.bat` and the correct `create.js` . see this [tuto](http://www.cerenta.net/blog/2013/02/07/package-your-sencha-touch-application-for-android/)